# jQuery populate Select2 instead of normal select

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to get the following work in a jQuery Select2 box. It does work good in a normal select but in a Select2 it goes wrong. Does anyone know the right syntax for this for a Select2?

```
$("#selectfield").load("querywith3variables.php?kid=" + $("#field1").val() + "&pid=" + $("#field2").val() + "&jid=" + $("#field3").val() );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to load the select before the call to .select2(). Like this:

```
$("#selectfield").load("querywith3variables.php?kid=" + $("#field1").val() + "&pid=" + $("#field2").val() + "&jid=" + $("#field3").val() );
$("#selectfield").select2();
```

In order to have a better code I also suggest you to use the remote feature of select2. You can find an example [here](http://select2.github.io/examples.html) under Loading remote data